# Does PIL work with skimage?

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, python-imaging-library, scikit-image

Why is is that when I do this:

```
from skimage import feature, io
from PIL import Image

edges = feature.canny(blimage)
io.imshow(edges)
io.show()
```

I get exactly what I want, that being the full edged-only image. But when I do this:

```
edges = feature.canny(blimage)
edges = Image.fromarray(edges)
edges.show()
```

I get a whole mess of random dots, lines and other things that have more resemble a Jackson Pollock painting than the image? Whats wrong, and how do I fix it such that I can get what I want through both methods?

for full code, visit my Github here:

https://github.com/Speedyflames/Image-Functions/blob/master/Image_Processing.py

Comment: Check what kind of type skimage returns and select the corresponding mode in your argument to fromarray to make sure, there is no type-based error (which is likely).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see what kind of image is produced by `skimage.feature.canny`:

```
edges = feature.canny(blimage)

>>> print(edges.dtype)
bool
```

It'a boolean image, `True` for white, `False` for black. PIL correctly identifies the datatype and tries to map it to its own 1-bit mode which is **`"1"`** (see [PIL docs about it](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/handbook/concepts.html#concept-modes)).
This looks broken though, it doesn't seem to properly get byte width or something like that.

There was an [issue about it](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/350), they seem to have fixed the `PIL` to `NumPy` conversion but apparently the converse is still broken.

Anyway, long story short, your best bet to successfully convert a binary image from `NumPy` to `PIL` is converting it to grayscale:

```
edges_pil = Image.fromarray((edges * 255).astype(np.uint8))

>>> print edges_pil.mode
L
```

If you actually need a 1-bit image you can convert it afterwards with

```
edges_pil = edges_pil.convert('1')
```